# Playwright Typescript how to convert a CSV file in to JSON object and use that data in Script to perform data driven testing

Tags: typescript, csvtojson

I have a scenario where i have to convert a csv file in to JSON object and use the data in script for performing data driven testing.
If the file has multiple rows of data, then script should be executed for multiple iterations.

Csv File

```
name,description  
CHOne,First Change  
CHTwo,Second Change
```

Expected JSON format

```
{
   "name":"CHOne",
   "description":"First Change"
},
{
   "name":"CHTwo",
   "description":"Second Change"
}
```

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide some code examples and actual/expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a 3d party library to parse `CSV` to `JSON` easier and then use a simple `for of` loop to run test with different objects.

```sh
npm i -D csvtojson
```

Parse from CSV file to JSON array and run test with different data:

```js
const csvFilePath = '<replace it with the path to csv file>'
const csv = require('csvtojson');

csv()
 .fromFile(csvFilePath)
 .then(users => {
    console.log(users) // will print
    /**
     * [
     *  {name:"CHOne", description: "First Change"},
     *  {name:"CHTwo", description: "Second Change"}
     * ]
     */

     // now you can run one test for each user's object
     for (const { name } of users) {
       test(`testing with ${name}`, async () => {
         // ...
       });
     }   
})
```